# Sync navbar and sections to show active class while user scroll down the page utilizing sections

Tags: javascript, html

I added a for each loop to highlight the sections when you scroll down as the active one however it applies the colors to all the sections, not the active one,

I need assistance regarding the for-each loop itself to stop the color being only at the active class and as well as syncing that with the navbar menu to show the active class there as well

the attached code snippet is down below

and here is a real-life example however I need mine to use with the section not list item

any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance everyone.

```js
/**
 * 
 * Manipulating the DOM exercise.
 * Exercise programmatically builds navigation,
 * scrolls to anchors from navigation,
 * and highlights section in viewport upon scrolling.
 * 
 * Dependencies: None
 * 
 * JS Version: ES2015/ES6
 * 
 * JS Standard: ESlint
 * 
*/

/*Note 
Please remove comments with starting word Future refernce its added just for future reference and reading purposes
/*

/**
 * Define Global Variables
 * 
*/

/*Scroll through sections Variables */
const pagesections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const navigationbar = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();



/**
 * End Global Variables
 * Start Helper Functions
 *
 */

/**
 * End Helper Functions
 * Begin Main Functions
 *
 */



// Reference WebDevelopment Udacity Zoom Meeting for Project


pagesections.forEach((elm, index) => {

  /* link text */
  let pagelinktext = elm.getAttribute("data-nav");
  let pagenewlink = document.createElement("a");
  let pagetextnode = document.createTextNode(pagelinktext);
  let pagenewlistitem = document.createElement("li");
  // reflow partition 
  pagenewlink.appendChild(pagetextnode);
  pagenewlistitem.appendChild(pagenewlink);


  //scroll to section

  // recalling pagenewlink and adding an event listener with click arrow function
  pagenewlink.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

    // Scroll into view scrolls into elm for thiscase which elm scrolls to
    elm.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  })
  fragment.appendChild(pagenewlink);

  /*
  adding this fragment to an existing element in page which would be the navigation bar
   acts as an imaginary element 
 */


})

navigationbar.appendChild(fragment);

// Setting Sections as active 


/*
  adding an event listener with a function means
  when user scrolls exceute this function
*/
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  /* for each loop added for too loop through all sections */
  /* there for foreachloop function excutes the getBoundingClientRect to scroll through section*/
  pagesections.forEach((pagesection, index) => {
    const pagereact = pagesection.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*
    .getBoundingClientRect(); accepts bottom top left right height and width 
    */
    // alert added as to find out section location of the X&Y Offset.
    //alert(pagesection.getAttribute("data-nav")+ pagereact.top);
    /* retrieve by Data Navigation Attribute */
    const navigationsection = pagesection.getAttribute("data-nav");
    if (pagereact.top > 0 && pagereact.top < 400);
    /* another alert to make sure sections are correctly placed
      alert(navigationsection);
    */
    //remove section 
    pagesections.forEach((activepagesection) => {
      if (activepagesection.classList.contains("active"))
        activepagesection.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right bottom, #304352, #d7d2cc)";
    })

    pagesection.style.background = "linear-gradient(to bottom, #c31432, #240b36";


    const pagelinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");

    pagelinks.forEach((pagelinks) => {

      if (pagelinks.innerText == navigationsection) {
        pagelinks.background = "white";

      }
    })


  });
})


// removing active class 





















//Set the menu item as active when the corresponding section is active.

/*Reference
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp
*/


//Return Top Button 

function scrollTopfunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    TopButton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    TopButton.style.display = "none";
  }
}



// At user click return to top of page for chrome , safari , firefox & most modern browsers


function pushtopfunction() {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}


/* User time out function when idle at 500 seconds */


setTimeout(function () { alert("User Time Out Message : 5 minutes"); }, 500000);


/*
  future reference
  make sure to name variables differently for future advanced code

*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Manipulating the DOM</title>
  <!-- Load Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Load Styles -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
  IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
  IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
     <div class="menucontainer">
       <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
     </div>
      
    </nav>
</header>
  <main>
    <header class="main__hero">
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Each Section has an ID (used for the anchor) and 
    a data attribute that will populate the li node.
    Adding more sections will automatically populate nav.
    The first section is set to active class by default -->

    <!-- Section 1 and bear in mind data-nav is used here as the text for the nav menu text added -->
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="active">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

            <!-- Section 2 -->

    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

            <!-- Section 3 -->

    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

            <!-- Section 4 -->

    <section id="section4" data-nav="Section 4">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/15/16/16/staircase-600468_1280.jpg" alt=:"staircase-600468_1280"
          width="150" height="150">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/08/00/39/steps-1081909_1280.jpg" alt=:"steps-1081909_1280"
          width="150" height="150">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/03/08/22/32/escalator-283448_1280.jpg"
          alt=:"escalator-5899073_1280" width="150" height="150">
      </div>
    </section>

            <!-- Section 5 -->

    <section id="section5" data-nav="Section 5">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 5</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

            <!-- Section 6 -->

        <section id="section6" data-nav="Section 6">
          <div class="landing__container">
            <h2>Section 6</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias
              non,
              vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
            </p>
          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Section 7 -->

    <section id="section7" data-nav="Section 7" >
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2 id="section7form">Section 7</h2>
        <label for"email">Email:</label>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        </br>
        <label for"Last_name.">Last Name:</label>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="Last_name">
        </br>
        <label for"First_name.">First Name:</label>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="First_name."></br>
        </form>
        </br>
        </br>
        <textarea class="text_area_class" rows="10" cols="25">Enter inquiry here.
        </textarea>
        </br>
        <input type="submit">
        <br>
      </div>
    </section>
    <button class="topbtnclass" onclick="pushtopfunction()">Top</button>

    <script src="js/app.js">
    </script>

    
  </main>
  <footer class="page__footer">
    <p>&copy Udacity</p>
  </footer>
```

```js
/**
 * 
 * Manipulating the DOM exercise.
 * Exercise programmatically builds navigation,
 * scrolls to anchors from navigation,
 * and highlights section in viewport upon scrolling.
 * 
 * Dependencies: None
 * 
 * JS Version: ES2015/ES6
 * 
 * JS Standard: ESlint
 * 
*/

/*Note 
Please remove comments with starting word Future refernce its added just for future reference and reading purposes
/*

/**
 * Define Global Variables
 * 
*/

/*Scroll through sections Variables */
const pagesections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const navigationbar = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();



/**
 * End Global Variables
 * Start Helper Functions
 *
 */

/**
 * End Helper Functions
 * Begin Main Functions
 *
 */



// Reference WebDevelopment Udacity Zoom Meeting for Project


pagesections.forEach((elm, index) => {

  /* link text */
  let pagelinktext = elm.getAttribute("data-nav");
  let pagenewlink = document.createElement("a");
  let pagetextnode = document.createTextNode(pagelinktext);
  let pagenewlistitem = document.createElement("li");
  // reflow partition 
  pagenewlink.appendChild(pagetextnode);
  pagenewlistitem.appendChild(pagenewlink);


  //scroll to section

  // recalling pagenewlink and adding an event listener with click arrow function
  pagenewlink.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

    // Scroll into view scrolls into elm for thiscase which elm scrolls to
    elm.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  })
  fragment.appendChild(pagenewlink);

  /*
  adding this fragment to an existing element in page which would be the navigation bar
   acts as an imaginary element 
 */


})

navigationbar.appendChild(fragment);

// Setting Sections as active 


/*
  adding an event listener with a function means
  when user scrolls exceute this function
*/
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  /* for each loop added for too loop through all sections */
  /* there for foreachloop function excutes the getBoundingClientRect to scroll through section*/
  pagesections.forEach((pagesection, index) => {
    const pagereact = pagesection.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*
    .getBoundingClientRect(); accepts bottom top left right height and width 
    */
    // alert added as to find out section location of the X&Y Offset.
    //alert(pagesection.getAttribute("data-nav")+ pagereact.top);
    /* retrieve by Data Navigation Attribute */
    const navigationsection = pagesection.getAttribute("data-nav");
    if (pagereact.top > 0 && pagereact.top < 400);
    /* another alert to make sure sections are correctly placed
      alert(navigationsection);
    */
    //remove section 
    pagesections.forEach((activepagesection) => {
      if (activepagesection.classList.contains("active"))
        activepagesection.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right bottom, #304352, #d7d2cc)";
    })

    pagesection.style.background = "linear-gradient(to bottom, #c31432, #240b36";


    const pagelinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");

    pagelinks.forEach((pagelinks) => {

      if (pagelinks.innerText == navigationsection) {
        pagelinks.background = "white";

      }
    })


  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Manipulating the DOM</title>
  <!-- Load Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Load Styles -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
  IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
  IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
     <div class="menucontainer">
       <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
     </div>
      
    </nav>
</header>
  <main>
    <header class="main__hero">
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Each Section has an ID (used for the anchor) and 
    a data attribute that will populate the li node.
    Adding more sections will automatically populate nav.
    The first section is set to active class by default -->

    <!-- Section 1 and bear in mind data-nav is used here as the text for the nav menu text added -->
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="js/app.js">
    </script>

    
  </main>
  <footer class="page__footer">
    <p>&copy Udacity</p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Real-life example of what i mean : https://codepen.io/joxmar/pen/NqqMEg

Comment: By the way... one minute consists out of 60 seconds... not 100...

Comment: fixed and done.

Comment: i guess i understand your idea! you mean something like this: https://demo.codeworkweb.com/cww-portfolio/smart-portfolio/
I want to do something similar too.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsPWEmfOQdU&t=402s.

It helped me create a hook that checks what the current section is and gives me the id.

```
function useOnScreen() {
  const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
        const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
        if(scrollY >= (sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3)) {
          setCurrentSection(section.getAttribute('id') ?? '');
        }
      });
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    
    handleScroll();
    
    // Remove the listener as soon as the component is unmounted
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [scrollY]);
  
  return currentSection;
}
```

So now I can change the state of items in my navbar to active or inactive by scrolling.

```
const currentSection = useOnScreen();
return (
  //...
  {props.entries.map((value, index) => (
      <SidebarEntry
        key={index}
        entry={value}
        active={value === currentSection}
      />
    ))}
  //...
);
```